# compactenum bold enumeration

Tags: paralist

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
    \begin{compactenum}[a)]
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \item ...
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

"a)", "b)" and "c" should be **bold**.

How can I force this with *compactenum*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\bfseries` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
    \begin{compactenum}[\bfseries a)]
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \item ...
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More information on that can be found in Section 3 "Formatting the Labels" (page 3) of the [`paralist` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/paralist).

Comment: you beat me to an answer... for the OPs information, this is mentioned in the doc http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf